# Is there a protection needed in the mcu connected to SCR?

Tags: microcontroller, scr

When an SCR is connected to high voltages (220Vrms) while it's gate is being controlled by pulses using a microcontroller powered by only 3V, is there a protection needed in the microcontroller?

My concern is that the mcu and my high voltage AC have common ground and I don't want any negative feedback in my mcu whenever there is a surge current or anything that may fry the mcu that is on standby on the the gate terminal. So do you usually add any protection on the mcu?

Comment: It's good practice to provide isolation either way, just for safety purposes if you have anything you might be mucking around with on the low-voltage side while it's running

Comment: What kind of isolation can I use?

Comment: Optocouplers or anything made to serve the same purpose. Since it's an SCR you could also probably use easily use a transformer.